# How does Apache load duplicate configuration options?

Tags: apache-2.2, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk

I have Apache installed on my server (AWS EC2 instance that is used by Elastic Beanstalk). There is the main configuration file `httpd.conf` that contains two configuration properties:

```
Timeout 60
KeepAliveTimeout 60
```

I need to change these parameters, but there is a problem that this main configuration file is overwritten after each application deploy. So any my changes are lost after some time (and default values are restored then).

I found that I can add another configuration file and put it in `conf.d` directory so that Apache will load this file as well. So I want to create such file (let's say `conf.d/custom.conf`) and put these two parameters here, but with changed values:

```
Timeout 180
KeepAliveTimeout 180
```

The main `httpd.conf` file contains the following lines as well:

```
Include conf.d/*.conf
Include conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/*.conf
```

And these lines are placed after `Timeout` and `KeepAliveTimeout` options.

So, the question is: **will options from a custom conf file override the options from the main file?** As a result I want to have `Timeout=180` and `KeepAliveTimeout=180`.

Comment: If I remember it properly Beanstalk kills instance each time during rebuild so your additional files will be lost. There definitely is a way to supply customization but I don't know, sorry. I prefer CloudFormation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to personalize your Elastic Beanstalk environment and to make those changes permanent, I suggest taking a look at [ebextensions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html). Also, take a look at the values [AWS recommends](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/apache-backend-elb/) for Apache back-ends running behind an ELB.